# Capturar Entity serializada en JSON con formulario Symfony

Tags: json, symfony2, rest

Estoy usando fos_rest en symfony 2.8. Tengo un cliente Angular que envia una entity serializada en JSON con el objetivo de persistirla en la base de datos. La misma posee tres entitys relacionadas.

Ej:

```
{"auto":
        {"usuario":{"id":1},
         "modelo":{"id":1},
         "color":{"id":1},
         "nombre":"Mi Auto",
         "kmActual":5300,
         "anio":2016}
}
```

Para capturarla tengo un formType como el siguiente:

```
class AutoType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('nombre', TextType::class)
            ->add('kmActual', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('anio', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('usuario', UsuarioType::class)
            ->add('modelo', ModeloType::class)
            ->add('color', ColorType::class)
            ->add('id');
}
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Auto',
        'csrf_protection' => false,
        'allow_extra_fields' => true,
    ));
}
```

Tambien tengo tres formularios UsuarioType, ModeloType y ColorType con estructuras muy parecidas a la de AutoType.

En el controller tengo lo siguiente:

```
/**
* Collection post action
* @var Request $request
* @return View|array
*/
public function cpostAction(Request $request)
{
   $entity = new Auto();
   $form = $this->createForm(AutoType::class, $entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);  
   if ($form->isValid()) {
       $entity = $form->getData();
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   );
       $em->merge($entity);
       $em->flush();           
       return $this->redirectView(
               $this->generateUrl(
                   'get_auto',
                   array('idAuto' => $entity->getId())
                   ),
                   Response::HTTP_CREATED
               );
   }
   return $this->view($form->getErrors(), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
   }
```

Usé merge porque al intentar hacer persist me intentaba insertar usuario, modelo y color como nuevos registros.
Haciendo etso inserta en la base de datos pero no actualiza la entity con el id insertado.

¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?